# Chrome devtools reporting the same CSS on the same line twice

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome DevTools is reporting the same CSS on the same line twice. Is anyone else seeing this? How can I fix it?

The problem occurs in both stable (40) and Canary (42)

[image]

`style.css` is being loaded exactly once. It is not minified.

[image]

Comment: Can you link to where you're seeing this?

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure style.css isn't being included/loaded twice? Check the Network or Sources tab.

Comment: @mikemaccana are you using a preprocessor or minifying your css?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a few options here:

## You may have included the stylesheet twice

If that is not the case (you're not using preprocessors or minification) I suspect have you included two references to the same file. **Use view source for this** - in the network tab they would appear as the same file.

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
h2.title {font-size: 30pt; color: #24a222; }
```

#### Result

[image]

## You may have declared h2.title twice on the same line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        h2.title {font-size: 30pt; color: #24a222; }h2.title {font-size: 30pt; color: #24a222; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This was my issue, I didn't realize it was duplicating the head twice when using Helmet in React.